# how to call mysql console using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql

Is it possible  to call mysql console using vb.net?Or to create a mysql database backup using vb.net.
I'm thinking if I could use a .bat file to execute the mysql dump code for me. And then call it using system.diagnostic.process.start in vb.net.
But I don't have any idea on how I can call the mysql console.exe. Because I have only experience in command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following check the documentation [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

```
 dim Program as string = "Path to mysqldump"
 dim Args as string = "-u user_name -p[password] -r file_name"
 system.diagnostic.process.start(Program,Args)
```